# Issue with Logic App having multiple triggers

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I have a scenario wherein I want to invoke the logic app as API (probably HTTP trigger) and at the same time, I would like to invoke the logic in recurrent fashion as well (probably using recurrence trigger). Since there can only be one starting trigger in the logic app, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic apps can only have one trigger.

Consider a second logic app which is recurrence based and calls the http triggered logic app. There is a built in connector for logic apps to call other logic apps.

Comment: Thanks. That helps.

Comment: According the docs for Logic Apps schema, you can actually have up to 10 triggers, not only one.

Answer (score 1):

Your Logic App can have up to 10 triggers.  Per the documentation on the Logic Apps schema definition:

> The definitions for one or more triggers that instantiate your workflow. You can define more than one trigger, but only with the Workflow Definition Language, not visually through the Logic Apps Designer.

See:  [Schema reference for Workflow Definition Language in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language)

Answer (score 0):

For this, the general pattern would be to use 3 Logic Apps.

One containing all the processing logic and flow.

Then as many Trigger Logic Apps as your situation requires, 2 as described.  The Trigger Logic Apps simply call the processing Logic App.